# What does The Man from Another Place in Twin Peaks symbolize?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, twin-peaks, david-lynch

The Man from Another Place is one of the major characters in Twin Peaks. He lives in The Black Lodge and dances like Laura's father.

Mike says that he lost his left hand and I read somewhere that The Man from Another Place is symbolizing the left-hand of Mike.

Is this the case or is there a different meaning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been awhile since I watched Twin Peaks, but I believe you're correct. He's Mike's left arm. If I remember right...I think there is a more direct explanation in *Fire Walk With Me*.

Comment: I've already watched Fire Walk With Me. But I guess it symbolizes something else, something connected to forest(because all things in Twin Peaks in some case are connected to forest).

Comment: @mesiesta You should watch it again, he clearly states "I am the Arm." Also, it's not the forest that is the focus, it's the Black Lodge, the portal to the Lodge is in the forest.

Answer (score 5):

In FWWM, not only does he say "I am  the arm", but at the end when Bob shows up with Leland after kiling Laura, he assumes the position of Mike's left arm and they say together "Bob, I want all MY garmonbozia." For Lynch, it doesn't get clearer than that for an answer.